# Volley or HttpURLConnection inside onResume() method is not working properly

Tags: android, android-volley, httpurlconnection, onresume

Hi i have a requirement of calling a web service when application goes to background and come back to foreground.I tried both Volley and HttpURLConnection but unfortunately both of them are not working for me. Some times it gives result but some times it is not.Below is my code

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    try {
        super.onResume();
       // app.activityResumed();
       // Toast.makeText(this, "QuizActivity Resumed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       /* if (session.getAreaName()!= null) {
            if (GetGeoCodingTask.mAutoCompText != null)
                autoCompView.setText(GetGeoCodingTask.mAutoCompText);
        }*/
        if (GetGeoCodingTask.mAutoCompText != null) {
            autoCompView.setText(GetGeoCodingTask.mAutoCompText);
        }

        autoCompView.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                autoCompView.dismissDropDown();
            }
        });

        LoadFoodListData();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

and my Method using HttpURLConnection is

```
private void LoadFoodListData() {
    try {
        StringBuffer chaine = new StringBuffer("");
        URL url = new URL(myUrl);
        connectionOpp = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        //connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
        //connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        connectionOpp.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

        connectionOpp.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connectionOpp.setDoInput(true);
        connectionOpp.setDoOutput(true);

        Log.d("Tag", "Webservice after connect");

        OutputStream os = connectionOpp.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(child.toString());

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        connectionOpp.connect();

        int responseCode = connectionOpp.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("Tag", String.valueOf(responseCode));
        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            // Toast.makeText(mContext, "Httpok",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            InputStream inputStream = connectionOpp.getInputStream();
            Log.d("Tag", "Webservice httpok");
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                chaine.append(line);
            }
        }
        String readJSON = chaine.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and Using Volley is

```
private void LoadFoodListData() {   

    final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(QuizActivity.this, "Please wait ...", "Fetching data nearby you ...", true);

    ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = null;
    try {
        jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, myurl, child,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            ongoing = response.getJSONArray("Listongoing");
                            if (ongoing != null) {
                                if (ongoing.length() != 0) {
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            livecount.setText("(" + ongoing.length() + ")");
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }

                            upcoming = response.getJSONArray("ListUpcoming");
                            Expire = response.getJSONArray("ListExpire");
                            if (Expire != null) {
                                if (Expire.length() != 0) {
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            expiredcount.setText("(" + Expire.length() + ")");
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        // dialogPro.cancel();
                        ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }, 
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
                   }
                });
    }   catch (Exception e) {
            ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        if (jsObjRequest != null) {
            jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        }
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
}
```

Any help would be very thankfull.

Comment: Your HttpURLConnection is not in an AsyncTask. Volley doesn't need a `runOnUiThread` call

Comment: can you explain more @cricket_007

Comment: And maybe both the arrays have 0 length. Why don't you want to set the text in that case?

Comment: You can't just use HttpURLConnection connection like that. Your app will crash with NetworkOnMainThreadException. Therefore you'd use an AsyncTask. Volley, on the other hand handles that for you, and returns to the UI thread on its own. `runOnUiThread` is unnecessary

Comment: no with the same url i run in rest client i am getiing result and array length is not 0 and also even when application is in foreground everything goes fine,the problem is with when app is backgrounded for some time and then foregrounded

Comment: Anyways, in the logcat, do you see any errors?

Comment: No it is showing as ActivityIdle binderproxy

Comment: That's unrelated.  In the first code sample, do you see "Webservice after connect", or not?

Comment: Yes upto "Webservice after connect" works fine,after that at responsecode debugger is skipping out

Comment: And you always see that output? If so, the request is not skipping out and one of your conditionals is evaluating differently then you wrote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126890/discussion-between-hari-krishna-and-cricket-007).

Comment: yes i always see that output,where should i have to change my code,please help me.

Comment: I didn't say to change anything. I said your code is not skipping the onResume, so the http request is always being made. I don't know how to reproduce your problem